# Does AskUbuntu encourage deleting old comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Generally, I don't delete my comments. I've seen several posts on AU where people's comments don't make sense, presumably because previous posters deleted their comments. It's worse when these comments don't reference previous comments (making them seem like wild tangents).

Deleting comments seems to be more prevalent on AU than other Stack Exchange sites, so I'm wondering what is the custom here for deleting comments?

The only reason I can think of to delete a comment is if it was no longer true (ex: pointing out flaws in an answer that have been fixed). However, this can be confusing if others in the discussion don't delete their comments.

Answer (score 5):

Anyone can delete their comments, and comments may be removed if flagged. The "why" is mostly a personal matter, although moderators should refrain from removing comments that provide some value to the post they're attached to when at all possible.

If you come across a comment thread that is superfluous, out of date, or broken due to deletions, flag the post they're associated with for moderator attention and request that they be removed.

Answer (score 5):

With some questions and answers quite a long list of comments evolve that may have been needed to clarify things. I always try to integrate important conclusions from these comments by editing the question or answer.

Then most if not all comments may be deleted to reduce clutter. This will make both the question, and the answer better.